# Editable QTabWidget

Tags: qt, qtabwidget, qtstylesheets

I want that user could rename tabs: clicking on current tab label should turn on editable mode.
The only way I can see is to use stacked layout + scrollarea + custom widgets + stackedwidget.
Can I do it with standard QTabWidget?

And one more question. Can I create custom pseudo states (like predefined :hover, :selected etc)?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can reimplement QTabWidget to get access to QTabBar and use [QTabBar::setTabButton](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtabbar.html#setTabButton) method. But sometimes it is difficult to adjust position of inserted widgets ;)
2. You can't create custom states, but you can use custom properties. See Q_PROPERTY macro and related [QSS syntax](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/stylesheet-syntax.html). Note, that styles will not updated on property change, so you should manually call polish/unpolish to force widget to use QSS.